# As ArrayList implements RandomAccess interface, is it faster than Array while traversing

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

As ArrayList implements RandomAcess interface, it finds element at any index with same amount of time. Does it use same interface while traversing. And if it does then is it faster than Array traversing?

Comment: Why would you think that? An array also allows random access (in fact, an `ArrayList` internally uses an array...).

Answer (score 2):

> Does it use same interface while traversing

What interface are you talking about? `List<T>`? well yes. `LinkedList<T>` also implements `List<T>`, but not `RandomAccess`.

> And if it does then is it faster than Array traversing

An `ArrayList` is using an array under the hood, so it cannot be faster than an array.

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` behaves just like an array.

It is essentially a `wrapper class` for an array that permits it to:

1. Grow dynamically
2. Allow for the selection and deletion of elements.
3. Access its elements just like an array.
4. And some other additional features such as searching for elements.

Except for item 3 above all are implemented as efficiently as possible but still add to the cost as they would if you had to provide that capability when using outright arrays.